# Ability to retract flags

Tags: feature-request, flagging

Is it possible to retract flags? It has happened a couple of times that I have flagged a post and in the time between flagging and a mod getting to it, it gets edited. I normally only flag if it looks like the post will not get improved but just occasionally the changes are made. It seems like it is an issue that could be easily dealt with.

Flagging generates work for the moderators which, if a post is edited to fix the problems, means unnecessary work - then I'd be happy to retract my flag (and actually I don't want disputed flags in my stats!)

Comment: That's a really good idea. We can retract close votes, but for flags this is not possible. And sometimes the quality improves after an edit.

Comment: @chris Agreed, *sometimes* they unexpectedly improve. Normally I'd only flag if I believe a post to be beyond repair, this is usually an assessment of the post and the user (ie If I ask for references are they likely to add references or take offence mail me a box of dog sh*t), occasionally the user surprises me.

Comment: I'll do the same. And usually this fits relatively well.

Comment: Why is this in MetaBio and not MetaSX?

Comment: Yeah, I remember getting a disputed flag because the user edited an answer I had flagged earlier..

Answer (score 4):

The "very low quality" flags are automatically dismissed if the post is edited. If you use those, these cases aren't a problem.

Unnecessary flags are not really a problem on this site, the total volume is pretty low. I wouldn't worry about this at all.

Comment: if I may ask, how do you know all these interesting behind-the-scene facts. Pretty intriguing

Comment: @ChrisStronks He's a mod, he knows everything xD

Answer (score 2):

Since [August 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/271002), you can retract flags on questions and answers, but not on comments. To retract a flag, click the flag link again and the button should become “Retract Flag”.

Today, the corresponding section of the [Help Center](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) has been changed accordingly:

> If, while your flag is still waiting to be handled, you re-open the flag dialog, you'll be presented with the option to *retract* your pending flag:
>
> [image: retract flag option]
>
> You cannot raise the same type of flag twice on a post: for example, if you retract a "spam" flag, you won't be able to raise a spam flag or an abusive flag in the future.
>
> Retract flags only when you're sure there's no need for the post to be flagged, or you become convinced that a more serious type of flag is needed.